# Inconsistent visibility of Ble advertising packets

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I am working on an android application where we are using ble device I find to get the rssi to calculate the distance. I am working on beacons for months together now but still understanding its behaviour is very difficult.

I  have a BLE device broadcasting at `10hz`(10 packets/sec).
Using `BluetoothLeScanner.startScan(scanCallback)` to get the rssi. Scan is continuous and So as of understanding we are suppose to get all 10 adv packets every sec. Since the scan is continuous there is no missing of data packets.
But the behaviour is different on every phone. I have tested on multiple phones and observed behaviour on few phones are as below,

```
Moto C Plus, AV: 7.0: 6-8 Callbacks/s

Redmi Note 4, Av: 7.0: 4-6 Callbacks/s

Moto G 2ng generation, AV: 6.0: android finds 1-3 callbacks for few seconds and no callbacks for seconds like 5,10 even for around 20+sec. 

One Plus one, AV: 6.0.1 : frequent is 1-3 callbacks and rest of behaviour is same as Moto G, no callbacks for seconds( like 5,10 even for around 20+sec)..
```

I don't have any device running android version 5 to find the behaviour on that.

Query:

Why this inconsistency in advertising visibility on android vary?Is it because of Android versions or individual android devices ?

(Sure that my BLE device is broadcasting exactly at 10hz)

I found varies blogs on beacons, Bluetooth low energy but not find sufficient information on this particular behaviour.Any Insights are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Not 100% of beacon packets are detected by Android devices for a number of reasons.**  Among them:

- Advertising packets are sent on a number of different radio channels, and the transmitter and receiver must be on the same channel at the same time.
- Radio noise sometimes causes errors in bits in the digital signal on the receiver side making the CRC (i.e. checksum) fail to match, so the receiver ignores the packet.
- Collisions in transmitted packets from multiple bluetooth devices in the vicinity happen.  When collisions take place, the packets are generally not received because they overlap eachother and interfere with eachother.
- Bluetooth advertisers automatically randomize the spacing of their packets so a transmitter at 10Hz does not send out exactly 10 packets every second.  Some seconds may have 11 packets, others 9.

Even in the best conditions you will not get 100% of packets transmitted at the receiver.  The best quality receivers getting strong signals in low noise environments might get 90% of advertised packets.

There is also a huge difference between different Android device models caused by using different bluetooth chipsets, different bluetooth antennas, different cases (which can block, amplify, or leak signals), signal interference with WiFi (which uses the same frequency band and often shares the same chip.)  As you have seen, the number of packets detected on some Android models can be significantly less even under the same test conditions.

The primary driver in packet reception rate differences between Android models probably has to do with the Bluetooth antenna and interference from WiFi circuits.  I have noticed that some Android models (such as the Huawei P9 Lite test device I own) show a much weaker RSSI (signal level) on average for the same beacon transmitter than the Android Nexus 5X receiver.  This signal is 20dB weaker.  Weaker signals relative to noise usually mean higher rates of packet loss for the reasons described above.  One of the first Android devices supporting BLE, the Nexus 4, could usually not detect BLE packets at all if WiFi was turned on.

On the Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge +, I noticed that depending on which channel the advertisement packet was on, the RSSI would be significantly higher or lower, possibly due to the antenna being less tuned to the slightly varying radio frequency of some channels.  This mean that the noise was higher relative to signal on the weaker channels, and a higher rate of packet loss when advertising was detected on those channels.  Unfortunately, Android APIs give no indication of which channel was used to detect a packet, so there is no way to correct for this.

**Bottom line: this is a complex issue that has many, many variables.  The results you are witnessing are not unusual.**

Comment: Thanks for sharing your knowledge with developers like us, it's very helpful.